# rails highlight helper - strange behaviour, when [""] passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well I bumped into some sort of bug or "feature" maybe. When I tried to add highlight search query feature in my project. When there is no search query on the page, highlight thinks, that `params[:query]` is an empty string and thus happens this:

```
2.1.1 :002 > query = ""
 => "" 
2.1.1 :003 > helper.highlight('Some String', [query])
 => "<mark></mark>s<mark></mark>o<mark></mark>m<mark></mark>e<mark></mark> <mark></mark>s<mark></mark>t<mark></mark>r<mark></mark>i<mark></mark>n<mark></mark>g<mark></mark>"
```

Is there a way to not highlight `if query is empty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highlight` will return the original text if the `phrases` argument (the array) is blank. You could call it like this:

```
helper.highlight('Some String', [query].select(&:present?))
```

If the `query` is blank, `phrases` will also be blank.